# $\chi^2$ Test of Independence

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, contingency-tables

I am trying to conduct a $\chi^2$ test of independence based on the following data.

```
          Type 1 Type 2  Type 3
House 1       36      1       2 
House 2       32      6       2
House 3        2      0       1
House 4        6      0       0
House 5        1      0       2
```

I understand how to complete such a question, however I encounter a problem calculating the expected frequencies. That is, a lot of the values are less than 5.

```
              Type 1      Type 2      Type 3
House 1    32.088889   2.9555556   2.9555556
House 2    33.777778   3.1111111   3.1111111
House 3     2.533333   0.2333333   0.2333333
House 4     5.066667   0.4666667   0.4666667
House 5     2.533333   0.2333333   0.2333333
```

I have seen in One-Way Frequency tables where one category is collapsed into another if one of the expected frequencies is less than 5. However, I have not encountered such a technique in a Two-Way test of independence, especially when there are so many expected frequencies that are less than 5.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this situation **without** using Fisher's Exact Test?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not permitted"?  What precludes the Fisher Test?

Comment: What I mean is, can this question be completed **without** using Fisher's Exact Test?

Comment: Some almost duplicates:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159057/alternatives-for-chi-squared-test-for-independence-for-tables-more-than-2-x-2/569662#569662,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/what-to-do-when-assumptions-are-not-met-in-a-chi-squared-test?rq=1, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135796/is-the-chi-squared-test-appropriate-with-many-small-counts-in-a-5x2-table